# How to get the sum of a floating point array?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, sum

So i am working to find the sum of a created array from an IO file, i have completed each of the arrays and the data itself prints out correct. Now when i work towards collecting data from one of the arrays, which happen to be real numbers, the statement will either send me into an infinite loop, even with using break, tell me that the float is not iterable, it will tell me that the float is unsubscribable, or it will only add the final number of the array

```
income = [234.94, 978.56, 769.55, 873.01, 102.21]


def income_report(income)
    total = 0
```

what i have tried:

```
total = total + income



total = total + income[0:4]



while income != '':
    for i in range(int(income))
        total = total + income
    print(total)



for i in range(len(income)
    total = total + income
print(total)



for i in range(int(income)):
    total = total + income[i][5]
print(total)
    


for i in income:
    total = sum(income)
print(total)



while income != '':
    total = total + income


with income:
    while income != '':
        total = total + income


data = income.readline()
while data:
    for income in data:
        total = total + income
    print(total)
```

to put it easily i have tried a number of things to get this to print out what it could be, i have even done the map technique, along with a number of others. I may have missed it somewhere along the line in frustration but a little assistance would be wonderful.

Comment: simply `sum(income)` should be sufficient!

Comment: Or even better, `math.fsum.(income)`

Answer (score 0):

```py
sum(income)
```

should help you out.
If you want to do it on your own,

```py
sum = 0
for element in income:
    sum += float(element)
```

Comment: having a variable called `sum` is a bad idea since `sum` is already a Python function

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be

```
sum(income)
```

This works for most of the cases, but its result can contain rounding errors.

For precise results, you should use [math.fsum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html)

```
import math

result = math.fsum(income)
```

If you really want to use a loop, then the best way would be:

```
result = 0
for number in income:
    result += number
```